# PHP Get Text Between Tags + The Tags Themselves

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to get all text between [tag] and [/tag] including the tags.

So this sentence.

`The cat said [tag]hi to dog[/hi] at the park.`

Using this function.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

I can return the text between the tags. But I want the tags also. Basically I want to scan my text for tags to make sure there is both a start and ending tag. Then allow me to edit the content and the tags. So change the [tag] and [/tag] to  **and**  around the text if both exist around the text.

I can do they with str_replace, but I don’t know how to combine the search for the open and ending tags, and replacing them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code, basically you need to detect the starting tag and ending tag, and do the substr include the tags as you want.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $posStart = strpos($string, $start);
    if (!($posStart !== false)) return '';
    $posEnd = strpos($string, $end);
    if (!($posEnd !== false)) return '';
    $len = strlen($end);
    return substr($string, $posStart, $posEnd - $posStart + $len);
}
```